# How to hide the div with class name of button on click?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need - button on click to hide each div, but here in my code only hide the first one then not working.

```js
const closeInnermenu = document.querySelector('closeInnrmenu');
const innerC = document.querySelector('.inner-container')
closeInnermenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  innerC.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```html
<div class="inner-container">
  <div>Demo 1</div>
  <button class="closeInnrmenu"></button>
</div>
<div class="inner-container">
  <div>Demo 2</div>
  <button class="closeInnrmenu"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives a clear console error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delegate

If you do not want to wrap in a div, use

```
document.addEventListener('click'
```

Here I wrapped

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("closeInnrmenu")) {
    tgt.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'none'
  }  
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div>Demo 1</div>
    <button class="closeInnrmenu"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div>Demo 2</div>
    <button class="closeInnrmenu"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the button using `document.querySelectorAll('.closeInnrmenu')` instead of `document.querySelector` since this will only give first matching element. Then iterate and add event listener to the button so that on click get the `closest` `div` and add style to it.

Also there is a type error here `const closeInnermenu = document.querySelector('closeInnrmenu');`. You need to pass dot as class selector

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.closeInnrmenu').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.closest('div').style.display = 'none'
  })

})
```

```html
<div class="inner-container">
  <div>Demo 1</div>
  <button class="closeInnrmenu">Close</button>
</div>
<div class="inner-container">
  <div>Demo 2</div>
  <button class="closeInnrmenu">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: [Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577971/295783) is more elegant

Comment: I did not want to add div cause I have to many div within this inner-container.

Comment: add a selector to target the element

Comment: @FrontEndDeveloper Just use the nearest static container - if none, use `document.addEventListener('click'`

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```js
let buttonClose = document.querySelectorAll('.closeInnrmenu')

for(let btns of buttonClose){
  btns.addEventListener('click', function func(e) {
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="inner-container">
  <div>Demo 1</div>
  <button class="closeInnrmenu">Close</button>
</div>
<div class="inner-container">
  <div>Demo 2</div>
  <button class="closeInnrmenu">Close</button>
</div>
```